# How to get data from two unrelated tables sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have two tables.

```
table_1: id, title, img_url, url, gif_url, date
table_2: id, title, url, date
```

Now I only get data from table 1 like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
```

How can I do the same for two tables with different amount of columns?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` if you fill up the missing columns,
e.g. by inserting constant values (like string '-', assuming that your urls are text) instead.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title, '-' as img_url, url, '-' as gif_url, date FROM table_2
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Testing this would be much easier, if a MCVE were available.

I used this as (hopefully basically equivalent) MCVE foundation:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE table_1 (a int, b int, c int);
INSERT INTO table_1(a,b,c) VALUES(1,5,7);
INSERT INTO table_1(a,b,c) VALUES(2,10,14);
CREATE TABLE table_2 (a int, c int);
INSERT INTO table_2(a,c) VALUES(3,11);
INSERT INTO table_2(a,c) VALUES(6,22);
COMMIT;
```

And the structurally identical test code:

```
select * from table_1
UNION ALL
select a, 42 as b, c from table_2
order by a LIMIT 3;
```

Gives the output:

```
a                     b           c
--------------------  ----------  ----------
1                     5           7
2                     10          14
3                     42          11
```

Note the line from table_2, starting with "3" and containing the 42 instead of "b". The 42 is the integer-analogon to the string '-'.